# What does ( type : load ) mean?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization, jquery-events

Does anyone know what Javascript `( type: load )` means? I gather its an event however it should be an object?

Any advice appreciated!

BREAK -> `var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData.jsonObj);`

Working with Google charts....

**charts.js**

```
(function($){
    
    
    var charts = {
        
        init: function(){
            
            this.services();
        },
        services: function(){
            var data = {
                uri : SITEURL + '/moduleTest/servicelist', //siteurl defined in index.php
                div : 'service-chart',
                title : 'Service List'
            }
            charts.ajaxCallback(data);
        },
        ajaxCallback : function(data){
            $.ajax({
               url : data.uri,
               type : 'POST',
               dataType : 'json',
               success : function(callback){

                   var jsonData = {
                       div : data.div,
                       jsonObj : callback,
                       title : data.title
                   }
                   drawCharts(jsonData);
                   
               }
            });
        }
        
    }
    
    $(function(){
       charts.init(); 
    });
    
})(jQuery);

google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});

google.setOnLoadCallback(drawCharts);

function drawCharts(jsonData){
   
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData.jsonObj);//Break point ( type : load )
    
    var options = 
        {
             'title': jsonData.title,
             'width':250,
             'height':300
         };

  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById(jsonData.div));
  chart.draw(data, options);

}
```

Services.php ( function test )

```
 public function servicelist(){ //TEST data
        if($this->input->is_ajax_request()){
            echo "
                {
                     cols: [{id: 'task', label: 'Employee Name', type: 'string'},
                            {id: 'startDate', label: 'Start Date', type: 'date'}],
                     rows: [{c:[{v: 'Mike'}, {v: new Date(2008, 1, 28), f:'February 28, 2008'}]},
                            {c:[{v: 'Bob'}, {v: new Date(2007, 5, 1)}]},
                            {c:[{v: 'Alice'}, {v: new Date(2006, 7, 16)}]},
                            {c:[{v: 'Frank'}, {v: new Date(2007, 11, 28)}]},
                            {c:[{v: 'Floyd'}, {v: new Date(2005, 3, 13)}]},
                            {c:[{v: 'Fritz'}, {v: new Date(2011, 6, 1)}]}
                           ]
                   }

                ";
        }
    }
```

Ok I may not have made any sense with the question(it was 6am).

I am passing in a json object to the my google charts constructor ( drawCharts() ).

```
var jsonData =  {
                         cols: [{id: 'task', label: 'Employee Name', type: 'string'},
                                {id: 'startDate', label: 'Start Date', type: 'date'}],
                         rows: [{c:[{v: 'Mike'}, {v: new Date(2008, 1, 28), f:'February 28, 2008'}]},
                                {c:[{v: 'Bob'}, {v: new Date(2007, 5, 1)}]},
                                {c:[{v: 'Alice'}, {v: new Date(2006, 7, 16)}]},
                                {c:[{v: 'Frank'}, {v: new Date(2007, 11, 28)}]},
                                {c:[{v: 'Floyd'}, {v: new Date(2005, 3, 13)}]},
                                {c:[{v: 'Fritz'}, {v: new Date(2011, 6, 1)}]}
                               ]
                       }

    console.log(typeof jsonData) === object // Correct, what I expect!
    console.log(jsonData) === load // not what I expect, I expect json object
```

Comment: Where is there anything about `type: load` in the code, aside from the comment?

Comment: @Matt function drawCharts(jsonData){} // firebug log jsonData = load

Comment: Sorry, I still do not understand. Could you clarify what you're talking about? An [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) would be super useful. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) is a useful tool for web dev SSCCEs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like this comment in the code:

```
//Break point ( type : load )
```

means to some agent (probably a debugger looking for certain comments) that there should be a breakpoint set here at page load time.